# ICursor implementation for ORM in MonoDroid

Tags: database, orm, cursor, xamarin.android

I'm trying to figure out how to make implementation of android database Cursor to wrap "ORMed" database layer.

To have ORM in MonoDroid we can use [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) project (very lightweight ORM) or [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite)

My thoughts are to implement [ICursor](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.Database.ICursor) interface and "wrap" ORM
For now I just can't set it in my mind how it should work, and should it work ever or not.
Should it load "framed" set of results, or fetch it one by one?
Which is better for performance, how to get column values - reflection or..?

So, actually question is: is it possible ever?
Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "problem" you're trying to solve with an ICursor implementation, perhaps you should be a little more specific as to what specific task you're trying to do.  The entire point of an ORM (and you missed [this one that also supports SQLite on Android](http://orm.codeplex.com)) is to abstract away the whole RDBMS paradigm from the code and give you an object-oriented paradigm instead.

An ICursor gives you back an updatable resultset from a SQL query - which means you have to know about rows, resultsets, queries and all of that.  An ORM gives back an object, or a collection of objects.  If you want to update one, you update the object and send it back to the ORM.

Now I fully admit that there are times when an ORM's might not provide the cleanest mechanism to do something that a SQL query might do well.  For example, if you logically wanted to "delete all parts built yesterday during second shift".  A lightweight ORM might give you all parts and then you have to use LINQ or similar to filter that to the right day and shift and then iterate that resulting collection to delete each, whereas with a SQL query you just pass in a `DELETE FROM Parts WHERE BornONDate BETWEEN @start AND @end`, but that's one of the trade-offs you face.

In some cases the ORM might provide a facility to do what you want.  For example in the OpenNETCF ORM linked above, you can cast your DataStore (if it isn't already) to a SQLDataStore and then you have access to the ExecuteNonQuery method, allowing you to pass in a direct SQL statement.  If still doesn't have a means to pass you back a record set because, as I said, returning database rows is really the antithesis or an ORM.

There's also some inherent risk in using something like ExecuteNonQuery.  If you want to change your backing store, from say a RDBMS like SQLite to something totally different like an object database, an XML file or whatever, then your code that builds and uses a SQL query breaks.  Admittedly this might not be common, but if code portability and extensibility and on your radar, then it's at least something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I know all advantages/disadvantages of ORM. So, I prefer to use ORM driven database layer in my Android applications, but Android supposes to use [ContentProvider class](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.Content.ContentProvider) which deals with ICursor. So I thought to implement kind of "compatibility" between ORM and ContentProviders. Ofcourse, simpliest way is not to use Providers, and maybe it is only way with ORM?

Comment: And thanks for link to OpenNETCF.ORM Framework, I really missed it while was looking for available ORMs